# Use Hybrid app functions in native and vice versa

Tags: android, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a some doubts in my mind. Is there any possibility to change the hybrid code as library and use that functions in a native android and vice versa?

I have some functions in native android code and some other functions of that same is in hybrid development. I wanted to use both the feature, native function in hybrid and hybrid in native. Is this is possible or not?

If yes, please direct me to the right way. And if no, why it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using these below links. 
It will help you to get on your track.

http://www.pycode.com/android/creating-a-phonegap-cordova-3.0-app-in-eclipse.html

https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted